# PHP header(Location:...) not working

Tags: php

Working on a sign up/log in form and for some reason header() redirect doesn't seem to be working.

```
if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $row['password'])){
    header("Location: account.php");
    if ($_POST['stayLoggedIn'] == 1){
              setcookie("id", $row["id"], time() + 60*60*24*365);
             }
    }
```

I have checked that the code works as intended by swapping the header() with an echo and print_r to check that the fields were working and they return the expected information.

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled? Is there anything being outputted before this content?

Comment: I would recommend that you put any code you want to be executed _before_ the `header('Location: ...')` instead of after.

Comment: as above and add `exit();` right after the header call. for errors -  add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);` at the top of the script

Comment: Looking at the errors it was something to do with the cookies. If all cookies are removed the page acts as expected. only when setcookie() is used it doesn't allow user to log in without using the StayLoggedIn tick box